# I have a doubt about the use of ～てみる

Tags: translation, meaning, syntax

とっさにシートに**触ってみたら**、ぞっとする程冷たかった。

Does the structure in bold mean: "I have immediately tried to touch the seat"?

Comment: Not a duplicate but informative: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28942/different-ways-to-try

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19040/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not translate the structure in bold (触ってみたら) that way.

> とっさにシートに触ってみたら、ぞっとする程冷たかった。

First off たら is indeed a conditional and it's key to understanding the construction as a whole.

The latter part means "it was cold enough to make me shiver."

- ぞっとする = [to shiver](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9E%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).
- [程]{ほど} is an expression of degree
- 冷たかった = it was cold.

The left hand part means "when i tried to touch the seat"

*シート = either seat or sheet
*　触る (here conjugated as 触って) = to touch
* ~てみる is a helping verb that means to "try"

I'd actually say   とっさに = for a brief moment applies to the entire construction.

So then we get "when I tried to touch the sheet/seat for a moment it was cold enough to make me shiver"